# Override Mailboxer Views in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mailboxer

I'm using Mailboxer into my app but I'm having some problems with the generated views (with `rails g mailboxer:views`). Seems to be the internal Mailboxer mailer are using some "hidden" templates and any changes over the existing views are not reflected on the sent emails.

Can anyone help me with that? One known alternative could be to program my own mailer class, but I think that it's a bit more of work to achieve the same thing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bug.  I am experiencing the same thing:
https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer/issues/324

Comment: Let me know if you have any new. I have to switch this project but the bug remains

Answer (score 0):

The origin of the problem is that "rails g mailboxer:views" copies the gem templates folders into "app/views" folder and the engine searches inside app/views/mailboxer.
The solution consists in moving the two generated (message_mailer and notification_mailer) folders into a subfolder "app/views/mailboxer".